# Why do we add probabilities in this problem?

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble understanding the resoning behind the following problem:

We're given a stick of lenght $1$. We choose a random point $X$ at which to break it, and then break it at a second point $Y$, also chosen randomly, so that we're left with three pieces. What is the probability that a triangle can be formed with these three pieces?

The solution manual separates the problem into two cases: if we assume that $X<Y$, the probability is $1/8$, and if we assume that $X>Y$, the probability is $1/8$. Therefore, the desired probablity is given by $1/8+1/8=1/4$.

What I don't understand is why we sum the probabilities in the two cases in order to get the final answer when it clearly makes no difference wether $X$ lies to the left or to the right of $Y$ (the probability that the three pieces form a triangle is the same in either case). For example, if I'm throwing a coin and I want to know the probability that it lands heads up, I won't sum the probabilities in the case where it's raining and in the case where it's not, since that has no effect on the event at issue (the probability of the coin landing heads up is the same whether or not it's raining). So why do we do so in that problem?

@edit

Full resolution:

Assume $X<Y$. Then we have three pieces of lenghts $X$, $Y-X$ and $1-Y$. By the triangle inequality, the conditions for these three pieces to form a triangle are: $$1) X+(Y-X)>1-Y\Rightarrow Y>1/2$$ $$2) X+(1-Y)>Y-X\Rightarrow Y<X+1/2$$ $$3) (Y-X)+(1-Y)>X\Rightarrow X<1/2$$ If substitute the inequality signs by $=$ and plot the resulting equations on a graph, we can see that the area enclosed by them is a right triangle with area equal to $1/2·1/2·1/2=1/8$. Since $X$ and $Y$ can only vary between $0$ and $1$, the sample space corresponds to the area of a square of side lenght $1$, and thus the probability is $(1/8)/1=1/8$. By a similar reasoning we can verify that the probability is the same in the case where $X>Y$. Therefore, the final probability is given by $1/8+1/8=1/4$.

Comment: Because the two cases are mutually exclusive and separately calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calculating the probability of some event $A$, and you have some event $B$ such that the probability of $A$ given $B$ = the probability of $A$ given that $B$ doesn't happen (in symbols, $P(A|B) = P(A|\neg B)$), then no, you don't add the probabilities. So if $A$ is flipping heads, and $B$ is raining, and you have $P(A|B) = P(A|\neg B) = \frac{1}{2}$, we can say $P(A) = \frac{1}{2}$ and not $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$, as you said.

If, however, what you've calculated is not the probability of $A$ given $B$ but the probability of $A$ *and* $B$ ($P(A \cap B)$), then you will have to add. For example, say we've calculated that the probability that you've flipped heads in the rain is $\frac{1}{20}$, and the probability that you've flipped heads not in the rain is $\frac{9}{20}$ (higher, perhaps, because it's more likely not to be raining than to be raining), then we have to add them to get the full the probability of heads.

The question, then, is which of those two things was your solution manual doing? Note that the $\frac{1}{8}$ for the valid $X<Y$ solutions is computed by comparing the area of the triangle to the *entire* sample space, so it's not the probability *given* $X<Y$; it's the probability that $X<Y$ *and* you have a valid solution. In our analogy, it's taking the number of cases in which you flip heads while its raining over the *total* number of cases, not the number of cases it rains. Thus you have to add the probabilities. (From the perspective of areas in the sample space: you have to add the areas of both solution triangles to get the total valid area, then take that over the area of the entire sample space.)

There's a way to solve the problem along the lines you were thinking too. Let $T$ be the event that the three lengths form a triangle. Instead of taking the area $\frac{1}{8}$ over the area of the entire sample space, take it over the area of the bigger right triangle corresponding to $X<Y$ (of area $\frac{1}{2}$). Then you get $P(T|X<Y) = \dfrac{\frac{1}{8}}{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{4}$. Finally, since you know that the $X<Y$ condition won't change the probability (as you reasoned), we can say $P(T) = \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: It's actually $1/8+1/8=1/4$. I've fixed that. I didn't post the full resolution because I didn't think it was important, but I've added it to my answer now.

Comment: @daniels Added to my answer to address the solution.